# string match using re in python re.search

Tags: python, regex

search() to match the string. Bellow is my code

```
import re

s = "hello world"

if re.search(r'hello world other exter string',s):
    print 'match success'
else:
    print 'no match'
```

in the above code it gives me no match. Even though "hellow world" is a part of the given string. i tried using re.match() also but getting the same result.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) first. You can simply do `s in 'hellow world other exter string'`

Comment: The order of the arguments is wrong, but "hello world" will never match the example string ("hello" vs. "hellow").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order of arguments is wrong. It should be `re.search(pattern, string)`:

```
if re.search(s, 'hello world other exter string'):
    print 'match success'
else:
    print 'no match'

[OUTPUT]
match success
```

Furthermore, as @thefourtheye stated, a simple `if substring in string:` would suffice. Regex is for detecting patterns in string. Say for example you wanted to find all the 5 letter words (although this can *also* be done without regex):

```
>>> print re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{5}\b', 'hello world other exter string')
['hello', 'world', 'other', 'exter']
```